# One Public IP, Private IPs, DNS Server and Multiple Servers

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, ip, bind, nat

I have lots of unanswered questions about these topics. So, lets begin.

First off all, I'm not a server and networking guru. I'm a regular PHP developer. And I've read allmost all of the articles about these things. But couldn't understand and find the solutions.

I have a new job and my boss wants me to setup a Windows Server 2012 R2 on a physical server and 2 virtual machines on that machine. First vm is Windows Server 2012 R2 and the other is Ubuntu 14.04. The goals are setting up Ubuntu server as DNS, PHP, etc. server and Windows server as ASP.NET server.

I can install and configure all of these using Hyper-V. The problems come when I'm trying to setup the network and DNS server.

We have an fiber internet connection with a modem and have "1 public IP". Lets say it `203.0.113.9`. And we have `192.168.x.x` private IPs. I've configured all static IPs on the servers using private IPs. Lets say phsical machine have `192.168.2.2`, vm Windows have `192.168.2.3`, vm Ubuntu have `192.168.2.4`. I can connect these servers using these private IPs on local network, like using remote desktop.

I've configured Ubuntu server and BIND using private IPs. I've configured ns1.example.com and ns2.example.com IPs as `203.0.113.9` on GoDaddy panel. I've configured example.com's nameservers on GoDaddy panel as ns1.example.com and ns2.example.com. I've put an index.html file for example.com on Ubuntu server. If I try to access example.com on Ubuntu server it works. I can see index.html. But when I try to access example.com on other computers it doesnt work.

How can I achive these working? I think it's not about BIND configuration or server configuration. It's all about this public and private IP things.

Let me give some examples.

I want to access remote desktop of Ubuntu server, or vm Windows or phsical machine at my home. But there is "1 public IP" address. So how the computers know which server I'm trying to access?

I want to host an ASP.NET site on virtual Windows machine and a PHP site on virtual Ubuntu machine. Lets say ASP.NET site is example1.com and PHP site is example2.com. How should I configure the zone files? Which IP addresses should I use when configuring the zone files? Public or private?

I know I can use phsical server for all of these things. But there is a problem too. When I configure static IP using public IP insted of private IP, I can't connect internet.

Btw, if it would work that way it still doesn't solve my problem. Because I need 2 vms on a phsical server.

Just please help me to understand this IP thing. How it works exacly, how can I configure it? I've watch lots of videos about IPs, gateways, subnetmasks but none of them answered my questions. Probably I try to find answeres on wrong topics. So, I'm here. Please help me to get out of this mass.

Comment: As per FAQ - only querstions from professionals and demonstrating an understanding of the technology. No "I a am a programmer, and lost at the technology, help me getting started" questions.

Comment: that public ip must exist on some device - either a router or one of your computers (probably a router).  That router will route traffic from the public internet to one of your internal servers.  I don't see how you can host 2 sites on 2 different internal servers but just 1 public address, I don't think that will work.  Unless you only need those 2 sites internally, with internal addresses.  Those internal addresses will only be available locally, not to the internet.

Answer (score 1):

You need a NAT and port forwarding...

```
     PUBLIC IP
         |
 -----------------
 |      NAT      |
 -----------------
  |              |
 TCP 80          |
 UDP 53          |
  |              |
Ubuntu          Everything else
Server          Private IP
Private IP
```

You have both the nameserver and the webserver on the Ubuntu box. So your NAT router will need to be configured to forward TCP 80 and UDP 53 to the Ubuntu box's private IP.

You really should also think seriously about actually having 2 nameservers, instead of just pretending to. The requirement to have two exists for a reason.